# Is it Possible to add Hide the one property based on other property?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

In my custom control I have 3 properties(State,Value,Count), State property with Enum(Dock,Float,Tab), if the Enum value(Float) means I want to Hide(Browsable False) Value property in WPF. Is there any possibility to do this with PropertyChanged of the State.

Comment: Seeing the other answer provided, do you mean hiding the property from use in code, or simply hiding the property on the UI (which would mean hiding a text box or something)?

Comment: what my need is if We set StateEnum to Float .Need to hide the Pubic property from my custom control.Same result as if we set Browsable attribute false for one public property.

Answer (score 1):

In the setter for State, just check what the value is.  If it's Float hide, else unhide.

```
private StateEnum _state;

public StateEnum State {
    get { return _state; }
    set
    {
        if (value == StateEnum.Float)
        {
            // Hide stuff
        }
        else
        {
            // Show stuff
        }
        name = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: what my need is if We set StateEnum to Float .Need to hide the Pubic property from my custom control.Same result as if we set Browsable attribute false for one public property.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you cannot hide a property conditionally.
However, there is a trick.

You can define a value interface and wrapper for your value property and implement for value and nonvalue states.

Example:

```
public interface IValueWrapper {}
public class BasicValueWrapper : IValueWrapper
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
public class NoneValueWrapper : IValueWrapper {}
```

Main Class :

```
public class MainClass
{

    private StateEnum _state;
    public StateEnum State {
      get { return _state; }
      set
      {
        if (value == StateEnum.Float)
        {
            // Hide stuff
            this.Value= new NoneValueWrapper();
        }
        else
        {
            // Show stuff
            this.Value= new BasicValueWrapper();
        }
        name = value;
      }
    }

    public IValueWrapper Value { get; set; }

}
```